# Could you find two linear maps that is not similar and linearly independent but $L^2 = H^2 = cI$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If $L \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $L^2 = cI$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. From $(gLg^{-1})^2 = gL^2g^{-1} = gcIg^{-1} = cI$ we could get all the conjugation of $L$ have such property. But not all of such linear maps live in the same conjugate class. For example, both $cI$ and $-cI$ has the property that $(cI)^2 = c^2I = (-cI)^2$. But the only matrix similar to $cI$ is $cI$ itself. So could you find two linear maps live in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ that $L^2 = H^2 = cI$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ but $L$ and $H$ are not similar and linear independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick $c=1, L=I$ and
$$ H=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
They cannot be similar as they have different traces and they are clearly linearly independent.